# Moving from Java to C++ API's

Tags: java, c++, api

There are some particular API's in Java that make it very good. However I would prefer C++ because of performance and "bleeding" edge support with OpenGL and OpenAL among the many libraries.

Which API's are there that are similar to Java2D (I know I can use OpenGL however I lack the matrix math understanding to fully use OpenGL in this way)? Also which GUI framework (non-native; platform independent) is the most used in C++?

Comment: "because of performance" you do realize that for many cases the advantages of the JIT compiler far outweigh any performance gains you could build into code statically.

Comment: Yes but java lacks support for very good API's. Also support that java does have often is behind.

Comment: If you want to use OpenGL have a look at JOGL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FLTK, Fast Light Tool Kit has some 2d functionality.  It's somewhat like swing and 2d mixed together.  It does focus more on the UI aspect but it may help you out.

http://www.fltk.org/

Comment: That is what Stroustroup uses for graphics in his new Swan C++ programming book. See Ch12 on this page:
http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/programming.html

Comment: I'm actually a student at Texas A&M where he is a faculty member.  I was lucky enough to have him teach some of it to us himself.

Answer (score 2):

If you want platform independent GUI framework for C++ check [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/).

Comment: It's called Qt, not QT. Qt = Q toolkit, pronounced "cute"; QT = QuickTime.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak much for Java2D equivalents but as far as GUI frameworks go, I've heard of two:

wxWidgets: http://www.wxwidgets.org/

Qt: http://qt.nokia.com/products/

Both of these are cross-platform and I believe widely used.

Comment: It's called Qt, not QT. Qt = Q toolkit, pronounced "cute"; QT = QuickTime.

Answer (score 0):

Try GTK--.  It has some features that make it a bit nicer an API than either wx or Qt.